Disable parallelism on installation time
1 PROBLEM
I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the following NOTE on CRAN submission:
* checking whether package 'fio' can be installed... [202s/46s] NOTE
Installation took CPU time 4.4 times elapsed time

Uwe asked if there's code running in parallel by default and, yes, there was: my code uses rayon (general parallelism) and faer (linear algebra, with rayon feature on) Rust crates. So I did a little refactor and added a method to allow the user to specify max threads. Then I started every example, vignette and readme by limiting threads to 1 to avoid parallelism.
Nonetheless, I still get the NOTE. Finally, out of despair, I've deleted vignettes, readme and enclosed all examples with \dontrun{} but that didn't work either.
So my question is, besides examples, vignettes and readme, what parts of code runs during installation of a R package? Is parallelism the only trigger for that NOTE or could it be something else?
2 TRIED AND FAILED
2.1 Disabling parallelism on examples, vignettes and readme
First try was setting set_max_threads(1) on the beginning of examples, vignettes and readme:
static THREADPOOL_INITIALIZED: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);

#[extendr]
/// Sets max number of threads used by fio
/// 
/// @details
/// Calling this function sets a global limit of threads to Rayon crate, affecting
/// all computations that runs in parallel by default.
/// 
/// Default behavior of Rayon is to use all available threads (including logical).
/// Setting to 1 will result in single threaded (sequential) computations.
/// 
/// Initialization of the global thread pool happens exactly once.
/// Once started, the configuration cannot be changed in the current session.
/// If `set_max_threads()` is called again in the same session, it'll result
/// in an error.
/// 
/// @param max_threads Int.
/// Default is 0 (all threads available). 1 means single threaded.

fn set_max_threads(max_threads: usize) {
  // Check if ThreadPoolBuilder has already been initialized
  if THREADPOOL_INITIALIZED.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
      println!("ThreadPoolBuilder has already been initialized.");
      return;
  }

  // If max_threads is 0, use the maximum number of available threads
  let num_threads = if max_threads == 0 {
      num_cpus::get()
  } else {
      max_threads
  };

  // global rayon threadpool
  ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
      .num_threads(num_threads)
      .build_global()
      .unwrap();

  // Mark ThreadPoolBuilder as initialized
  THREADPOOL_INITIALIZED.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
}

2.2 Disabling with .onAttach
Based on this issue I've tried replicating their approach also without success:
# disable parallelism on CRAN
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  if (Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_LIMIT_CORES_") != "") {
    if (as.logical(Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_LIMIT_CORES_"))) {
      packageStartupMessage("_R_CHECK_LIMIT_CORES_ is set to TRUE. Running on 2 cores")
      Sys.setenv("RAYON_NUM_THREADS" = 2)
    }
  }
}

2.3 Disabling faer parallelism
Also tweaked 2.1 in order to explicitly deactivate faer parallelism:
fn set_max_threads(max_threads: usize) {
  // Check if ThreadPoolBuilder has already been initialized
  if THREADPOOL_INITIALIZED.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
      println!("ThreadPoolBuilder has already been initialized.");
      return;
  }
  // If max_threads is 0, use the maximum number of available threads
  let num_threads = if max_threads == 0 {
      num_cpus::get()
  } else {
      max_threads
  };

  // control faer thread pool
  faer::set_global_parallelism(faer::Parallelism::Rayon(num_threads));

  // for everything else?
  ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
      .num_threads(num_threads)
      .build_global()
      .unwrap();
  // Mark ThreadPoolBuilder as initialized
  THREADPOOL_INITIALIZED.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
}


Do you have unit tests that might involve parallelization? Also, note that the parallelization seems to occur during R cmd install. I suggest you take this to the R-package-devel mailing list. Don't forget to provide a link to your source code.

@Roland, yes there are tests. Also tried removing them. I'll bring it to the mailing list, thanks!

Turns out there's nothing to do with code running in parallel (exemples, vignettes, tests & readme), but cargo build compiling in parallel. Fix was just add -j 2 flag to cargo build in makevars and makevars.win (or -j 1 for single thread). Kudos to Gábor and Ivan on R-pkg-devel mailing list.
cargo build -j 2 --lib --release --manifest-path=./rust/Cargo.toml --target-dir $(TARGET_DIR)

